# IHttpHandler doesn't load image after deployed to web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, shared-hosting

I am now having problem of deploying my website to a shared windows hosting.

I am currently hosting it with hostgator.

The problem is, my ThumbnailHandler which is supposed to return an image file, stopped working once the project is **deployed to web server**. It works properly in **local IIS** virtual folder, and **vs2010 debug**.

e.g-

> http://www.myweb.com/imageHandler.ashx?i=0 - ***ERROR***
>
> http://www.myweb.com/imageHandler.ashx - ***ERROR***
>
> http://www.myweb.com/image-handler?i=0 - *(routed with IRouteHandler)*
>   ***ERROR***
>
> http://www.myweb.com/img/theimage.jpg - ***OK !***

No exception is thrown. If I open the url, it returns 'The image (*path*) cannot be displayed because it contains error'.

ThumbnailHandler.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.Flush();
    Size maxSize = new Size(98, 98);
    byte[] buffer = Imaging.GetImage(context.Server.MapPath("~/img/noimage98.png"), maxSize).GetBytes(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    try {
        Int32 index = GetImageIndex(context);
        maxSize = GetMaxSize(context);
        if (index < 0 || maxSize == null)
            throw new Exception("Index size is not specified.");
        String authToken = GetAuthenticationToken(context);
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = AdvertisementDirectory.GetDirectoryInfo(authToken);
        List<FileInfo> fileInfos = AdvertisementDirectory.GetImageFileInfoList(directoryInfo);
        using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = Imaging.GetImage(fileInfos[index].FullName, maxSize)) {
            buffer = thumbnailImage.GetBytes(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
```

web.config

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" fileEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>

<pages buffer="true" clientIDMode="Static" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="true" enableEventValidation="true" enableSessionState="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Auto" >
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ATK" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>

<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="Tradepost.ThumbnailHandler, Tradepost"/>
</httpHandlers>

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="40000" maxUrlLength="260" maxQueryStringLength="2048" requestLengthDiskThreshold="80" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="5000" enableKernelOutputCache="true" enableVersionHeader="true" requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true" shutdownTimeout="90" delayNotificationTimeout="5" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" enableHeaderChecking="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true" apartmentThreading="false" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Has anyone experienced this before? I've also tried to check folder permission security setting. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

> *Note: This occurs to any images in any folder.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the issue.
Literally my host provider doesn't support full trust policy, so I had to change it to medium trust. Even if I set the full trust on my web.config, It'll just change it back to medium trust or display the error.

So, the error occured on my 'GetImage' function, which was

```
public static System.Drawing.Image GetImage(String fileName, System.Drawing.Size maxSize) {
    System.Drawing.Image result = null;
    try {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
            using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs, true, false)) {
                Size sz = GetProportionalSize(maxSize, img.Size);
                result = img.GetThumbnailImage(sz.Width, sz.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

***or***

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName)) {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
        using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sr.BaseStream, true, false)) {
            System.Drawing.Size sz = GetProportionalSize(maxSize, img.Size);
            result = img.GetThumbnailImage(sz.Width, sz.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
    fs.Close();
}
```

***and throws...***

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckNReturnSO(PermissionToken permToken, CodeAccessPermission demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Int32 unrestrictedOverride, Int32 create) at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Assert(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Assert() at [Snipped Method Name] at ReportExprHostImpl.CustomCodeProxy.[Snipped Method Name] The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer
```

**BUT,**
I still don't know **WHY** the following code **WORKS**

```
using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName)) {
    System.Drawing.Size sz = GetProportionalSize(maxSize, img.Size);
    result = img.GetThumbnailImage(sz.Width, sz.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

I've tested it with my host provider and my local IIS with this in my ***web.config***

```
<trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>
```

Anyway, it works now.
I still haven't got the right time to find out why Stream type object would act differently to Image.FromFile, since what I know is those two still streams for the file.
I'll post more update if I found out something interesting.

Cheers.

Comment: So, instead of using `FromStream` this trust issue is solved if I use `FromFile`.

Answer (score 1):

When Images are  load in img folder , **img** folder have no access to read/write files.
So first give all access to **img** folder to read and write images .

or you try to give full path of image because some time client server have different root path So `Server.MapPath`

not get exact path of image .

May you try path of starting domain name define in web.config appsetting control and then this 
path use in handler to get path of images.

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="ProjectName" value="/www.myweb.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

In handler page use

```
string ProjectName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectName"].ToString().Trim();
byte[] buffer = Imaging.GetImage(ProjectName+"/img/noimage98.png", maxSize).GetBytes(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: As I stated, I had triple checked the corresponding folder permission and allow every single user to access it.

In case of full path image, since it's shared windows hosting. I don't think I'd be able to access the root path.
But, I haven't tried to get image from 'url', I'll try that and update you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hei, using stream from Uri actually works. Thanks :).

But for some reason, I still need to use MapPath approach. Any other suggestion for me?